# How do I set a DIV to be absolute within another specific DIV?

Tags: html, css

I have 3 DIVs that are wrapped inside a container. I had to wrap them in the container in order to center them on my page laid out the way I wanted them. Within these 3 DIVS are DIV headers to make title bars for each DIV. The title bar DIV headers are positioned to absolute so they expand across the top of the DIVs they are in. That works fine. But as soon as I put the 3 DIVS in the container, the header DIVs become children to the container and start expanding across it rather than their respective DIVs. Is there a way to get them to go back?

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/mh2ez7x9/2/

```css
.main {
  border: 2px solid red;
  position: relative;
  width: 740px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 220px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.update {
  position: none;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #474747;
  width: 700px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  left: 280px;
  top: 220px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12pt;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 0 #000026, 0px 1px 0 #000026, 0px -1px 0 #000026, 1px 0px 0 #000026, 1px 1px 0 #000026, 1px -1px 0 #000026, -1px 0px 0 #000026, -1px 1px 0 #000026, -1px -1px 0 #000026, 0px 0px 0px #000026;
  font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #000000;
  z-index: 1;
}
.newmembers {
  position: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: #474747;
  width: 350px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  left: 280px;
  top: 500px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12pt;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 0 #000026, 0px 1px 0 #000026, 0px -1px 0 #000026, 1px 0px 0 #000026, 1px 1px 0 #000026, 1px -1px 0 #000026, -1px 0px 0 #000026, -1px 1px 0 #000026, -1px -1px 0 #000026, 0px 0px 0px #000026;
  font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #000000;
  z-index: 1;
}
.latest {
  position: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: #474747;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  left: 680px;
  top: 500px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12pt;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 0 #000026, 0px 1px 0 #000026, 0px -1px 0 #000026, 1px 0px 0 #000026, 1px 1px 0 #000026, 1px -1px 0 #000026, -1px 0px 0 #000026, -1px 1px 0 #000026, -1px -1px 0 #000026, 0px 0px 0px #000026;
  font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #000000;
  z-index: 1;
}
.miniheaderA {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  border: 2px none red;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 20px;
  background-image: url('../images/redboxtext.png');
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px #000000;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}
.miniheaderM {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  border: 2px none red;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 20px;
  background-image: url('../images/orangeboxtext.png');
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px #000000;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}
.miniheaderU {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  border: 2px none red;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 20px;
  background-image: url('../images/blueboxtext.png');
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px #000000;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">

  <div class="update">
    <div class="miniheaderU">
      <h3>News</h3>
    </div>
    Welcome to the all new website!
  </div>


  <td valign="top">
    <div class="newmembers">
      <div class="miniheaderM">
        <h3>New Members</h3>
      </div>
      <?php echo "new members!"; ?>
    </div>

    <div class="latest">
      <div class="miniheaderA">
        <h3>Latest Content</h3>
      </div>
      <?php echo "new content"; ?>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Use `position:relative;` on the container element

Comment: ok. That fixed the headers but now my DIVs are shifted weirdly all over the page. I updated this post.

Comment: Can you post a JSFiddle that re-produces this issue?

Comment: ok i made one. how do i send it?

Comment: Save it and post the link in your question

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mh2ez7x9/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the others have misunderstood your goals. Feel free to see my codepen:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MeyYWV?editors=1100

I did a bit of reorganization of the rules for you, and I added a class for my ease:

```
.update, .newmembers, .latest{
  padding:0 0 1em;
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  margin: 10px 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #474747;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12pt;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 0 #000026, 0px 1px 0 #000026, 0px -1px 0 #000026, 1px 0px 0 #000026, 1px 1px 0 #000026, 1px -1px 0 #000026, -1px 0px 0 #000026, -1px 1px 0 #000026, -1px -1px 0 #000026, 0px 0px 0px #000026;
  font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #000000;
  z-index: 1;
}
.update {
  width: 700px;
  height: 200px;
}

.newmembers {
  width: 350px;
  height: 200px;
}
.latest {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

Mohamed Athif was right on the H3, so I added in his rule.

Comment: No I wasn't wrong, his code is a mess, I cleaned up and remove all the messiness on it and it is doing what OP wants :) I just missed a line to clean.

Comment: i forgot to add the h3 tag i used. 
`h3 {
  margin-bottom: -30px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}`

Comment: @BuddyRoach have you look at my answer at least?

Answer (score 0):

Use position: relative on classes miniheaderU,miniheaderM and miniheaderA. insert class in H3 tag and in css use margin-top: 0px.

such that you html code is

```
<div class="main">

  <div class="update">
    <div class="miniheaderU">
      <h3 class="gj">News</h3>
    </div>
    Welcome to the all new website!
  </div>


  <td valign="top">
    <div class="newmembers">
      <div class="miniheaderM">
        <h3 class="gj">New Members</h3>
      </div>
      <?php 
    echo "new members!";
    ?>
    </div>

    <div class="latest">
      <div class="miniheaderA">
        <h3 class="gj">Latest Content</h3>
      </div>
      <?php 
    echo "new content";
    ?>
    </div>

</div>
```

and insert in css below code

```
H3.gj {
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```